# input is empty, but the function still runs

Tags: php

I have this input field:

```
<input type="text" id="image_url_input" class="url_input" /></div>
```

And this php code:

```
$title = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,htmlentities($_POST['title']));
$content = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,nl2br(htmlentities($_POST['content'])));

$sql = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO nfeed (title, content) VALUES 
('$title','$content')");

if (isset($_POST['image'])) { //This one runs whether or not the input field is empty 

        $image = file_get_contents($_POST['image']);

        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM nfeed WHERE ID=(SELECT max(ID) FROM nfeed)"); //Here the renaming of the image starts...

            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

            $id = $row['ID'];

            $new_name = $id . "_" . "000.jpg";

                if(file_exists("../images/" . $new_name)) {
                    $new_name = $id . "_" . "001.jpg";
                }

            file_put_contents("../images/" . $new_name, $image);

            $sql = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE nfeed SET file='{$new_name}' WHERE ID='{$id}'");

        }
```

It runs perfectly well when I input an image URL... and when I don't - that's the problem

I've tried to write `file_get_contents($_POST['image'])` to a .txt file, and guess what: it was completely empty!

I've ran the same function before switching to AJAX. It was a plain grab-from-form code, that added an image if it was uploaded from the user's PC.

I've also tried: `if (isset($_POST['image']) && ($_POST['image'] != 0)) {` and still no luck. Why does it think that I've inputed something?

Comment: There is no text field named `image` in your HTML. You should post your complete relevant HTML in your questions. And `if (isset($_POST['image']) && ($_POST['image'] != '')) {` you should write this instead of `!= 0`

Comment: while you post a form it's send all fields (except checkboxs) and by default all fields will be set but if you want to check has value or not use empty() and !empty()

Comment: @Ejay I pass my values through AJAX, so the content of the <div id="image_url_input"> gets passed as "image" and processed as "$_POST['image']". Thanx for the `($_POST['image'] != '')` tip - I tend to make this mistake often.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
if(!empty($_POST['image']))
```

Isset checks if the array ($_POST) key is present.

So if the value is empty the isset will return true, you need to check if it's empty.